# NodeJS: "ENOENT" warning messages with sessions

Tags: node.js, session, express, express-session

I'm using node with the express-session and session-file-store packages.  The session data is stored as files in the root directory, using the session-file-store package.  However, now my logs are being clogged because the message `[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: ENOENT, open 'sessions/_jl2ijMBQHIvv8M1mYTcnFZGqwGo0t-v.json'` is appearing 5 times per session cookie accessed in a short burst.  What could be causing this error?  It's happening both on my windows development machine and on my ubuntu server.  It can't access the file apparently, but the sessions still work.

Here is one of the bursts of errors I received:

```
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: ENOENT, open 'sessions/tRI6WeZEO2Uyvr4ZaUGW6_CU32RjvFpW.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: ENOENT, open 'sessions/tRI6WeZEO2Uyvr4ZaUGW6_CU32RjvFpW.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: ENOENT, open 'sessions/tRI6WeZEO2Uyvr4ZaUGW6_CU32RjvFpW.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: ENOENT, open 'sessions/tRI6WeZEO2Uyvr4ZaUGW6_CU32RjvFpW.json'
[session-file-store] will retry, error on last attempt: Error: ENOENT, open 'sessions/tRI6WeZEO2Uyvr4ZaUGW6_CU32RjvFpW.json'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I literally just ran into the same messages when I was trying my first NodeJS/Express Sample Project out.

I managed to determine that at least in my sample project that the Session is Declared Destroyed but the Cookie never cleared, so the next page that loaded used the old cookie to try and access the expired session (already deleted) causing the messages to get logged.

This might not be the same issue for you, but figured it was worth sharing... The lazy alternative is to replace the logFn option with an empty function:

```
new filestore({logFn: function(){}})
```

Comment: Another solution: use option session-file-store option `retries: 0`: it will give up on unknown sessions without retrying. In most use cases (local filesystem), retrying is useless.

Answer (score 2):

In my case that has not been as main problem, because **session-file-store** is a part of **express-session** and when **express-session** can't find session file, he just create new file.

And then you can just hide errors log as suggested earlier

```
new filestore({logFn: function(){}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same problem by `chmod +x sessions`